# Invalid client Zoom Post request

Tags: api, token, access-token, zoom-sdk

I try to get acces token from the zoom api with a post request but i don't understand why i have this error:

```
  reason: 'Invalid client_id or client_secret',
  error: 'invalid_client'
```

My code :

```
    let clientID = "exemple"
    let clientSecret = "exemple";
    const zoomtokenep = "https://zoom.us/oauth/token";
    const myappredirect = "http://localhost:3000/campaigns";
    let url = zoomtokenep + "?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + "code_exemple" + 
     "&redirect_uri=" + myappredirect;
    let auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(clientID + ':' + clientSecret).toString('base64');

    await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Autorization": auth,
        },
    })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```